# Cannot create stored procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have the following piece of statement entered into MySQL5.6 Command Line Client. However, the following error was received. I haven't even been able to add in END// Delimiter; after the select statement.

At the same time, i was wondering after the stored procedure has been created successfully, how do i CALL the stored procedure without the command line but using java codes.

Kindly assist. Greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a space between `DELIMITER` & `//`.